# How to iterate through values in an array containing arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to echo out the values of an array containing language information in a foreach-loop. Each language in het array contains a second array with a language description and a permalink of the current page. I want to use the permalink for creating hreflang tags in my site's header.

I have trouble accessing the correct values in the array. What is the best approach for this? I tried a foreach loop, but this returned a PHP notice 'array to string conversion' because I tried to echo out an array as a string.

My foreach loop looks like this:

```
$lang_list = stella_get_lang_list();

var_dump($lang_list);

    foreach ($lang_list as $lang) {
        foreach ($lang as $attr)) {
        echo '<link rel="alternate" hreflang="' . $lang . '" href="' . $attr . '"/>';
    }
}
```

This is the var_dump of the array:

```
array (size=4)
nl' => 
    array (size=2)
    'title' => string 'Dutch' (length=5)
    'href' => string 'www.example.dev/page/' (length=24)
'en' => 
  array (size=2)
  'title' => string 'English' (length=7)
  'href' => string 'www.example.dev/en/page/' (length=27)
'de' => 
  array (size=2)
  'title' => string 'German' (length=6)
  'href' => string 'www.example.dev/de/page/' (length=27)
'fr' => 
  array (size=2)
  'title' => string 'French' (length=6)
  'href' => string 'www.example.dev/fr/page/' (length=27)
```

Note: Stella is a Wordpress plugin, but I posted the question here because the essence of the problem is PHP related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($lang_list as $langId => $lang) {
    echo '<link rel="alternate" hreflang="' . $langId . '" href="' . $lang['href'] . '"/>';

}
```

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, this returned the required result!